# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, actionresult

I tried the solutions posted on StackOverflow, but none of them worked.
I have a method calling a web service. The code is as following and I keep getting a compiler error:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult <List<items>>>getitems()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var Res = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/sub", ids);
        Res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var Response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;   
            var sub = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(Response);
            List<items> item = sub.ToObject<List<items>>();
            return Ok(item);
        }
    }
```

Then I call the method from a different class as following:

```
    public async Task<List<items>> getService(List<string> ids)
    {
        var IdentificationIdsToOrder = new JObject();
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            var newId = new JProperty("ids", id);
            IdentificationIdsToOrder.Add(newId);
        }
        _controller = new getitems();
        var Res = await _controller.getitems();         
        var ItemList = Res.Result;
        return ItemList;
    }
}
```

Here it goes wrong with the return value and I can't compile.

What I'm missing?

Comment: There are inconsistencies with the code shown. Provide a [mcve] that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Nkosi sorry, I was trying different apporches  and mixed some code together, following different examples from Stack overflow

Comment: This is understood. But in order to get help you need to have a least a base set of code that we can use to reproduce your problem and find a solution.

Comment: Yes, I edited the post method. which is actually working when I tested with postman. but the issue is that I can't get to work when I call it from a different class

Comment: Ok now my question would be why are you using `ActionResult<T>` and calling it the way you do in the example?

Comment: I am just trying to understand what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @dolly_do Stop using `var`. It confuses you for what is going on - use explicit types for all variables... (If you have R# it can convert `var` to explicit types automatically... but that's will be less educational)

Comment: @Nkosi I use the ActionResult<T> to call a web api post method

Comment: ActionResult is used with Mvc to return response when the action method is called. I would extract your api calling code into another class that simply returns the List<> and then use that in the `getitems` action and in your `getService` method.

Comment: @Eugene S. it worked according to your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

In `getService` method you should use `var ItemList = Res.Value;` in place of `var ItemList = Res.Result;`

```
public async Task<List<items>> getService(List<string> ids)
{
    var IdentificationIdsToOrder = new JObject();
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var newId = new JProperty("ids", id);
        IdentificationIdsToOrder.Add(newId);
    }

    _controller = new getitems();
    var Res = await _controller.getitems();         
    var ItemList = Res.Value;
    return ItemList;

}
```

Comment: this worked only after I removed the action result from the method I'm calling. That is why I up-voted Eugene S. comment